# All select /deselect button

Tags: c#, datagridview, deselect

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AaA2.png)I want to make n 'all select' button in datagridview.
datagirdview has checkbox column.
If I press the Select All button, I can select the entire selection. 
If I press the Select All button again, I want to release the entire selection.
I can only Select All, no DeSelect All .
Please help me :(

```
private void Btn_selectall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           

        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            item.Selected = true;
            item.Cells[0].Value = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need the same thing with false, rather then true. Wich code option you take, depends on teh current value of the Select all. I am not quite sure what the question is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
private void Btn_selectall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().All(r => r.Selected))
    {
        // deselect all
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            item.Selected = false;
            item.Cells[0].Value = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // select all
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            item.Selected = true;
            item.Cells[0].Value = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But i can't use   dataGridView1.Rows.All . All is not contained in datagridviewrowcolletion

Comment: It is an extension method under `System.Linq` so add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your file.

Comment: I've already added it. But it cannot work. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: Ah, try again now (see I've added `.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()`)

Answer (score 1):

You can invert the values like so

```
item.Selected = !item.Selected;
item.Cells[0].Value = !item.Cells[0].Value;
```